# SAPUI5 i18n dialogues retrieval

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

In order to get a dialogue value from the UI5 `i18n`-property file, one of the following approaches can be used:

```js
this.getModel("i18n").getProperty("%WANTED_PROPERTY%");
this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("%WANTED_PROPERTY%");
this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("%WANTED_PROPERTY%");
```

Does UI5 work differently when I get an `i18n`-dialogue value via:

- `getModel()` → `getProperty()`,
- or via `getModel()` → `getResourceBundle()` → `getText()`,
- or via `getView()` → `getModel()` → `getResourceBundle()` → `getText()`?

In other words, is there any real difference (e.g. performance, reliability, etc.) between these three techniques, or it's more a matter of a taste, which way to use in order to retrieve a dialogue value?

Comment: The approach without `getView()` does not work at all - there's no `getModel()` method on the controller (unless you defined it in your BaseController or something like this). As for the other two, `getProperty()` does not allow you to interpolate placeholders - if your text is "My name is {0}", for example, then it will return this literal string, while with `getText()` you can do `getText("nameTxt", ["Mike"])` to get "My name is Mike".